# What does "liveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO)" mean?

Tags: android, android-livedata, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm doing a read on coroutines because I've been only using GlobalScope for a long time and thought I'd go deeper, it's impressive how much stuff I'm missing.
So I've been reading on https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines and I found this:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val userId: LiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    val user = userId.switchMap { id ->
        liveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(database.loadUserById(id))
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain what this line means exactly:

```
liveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO)
```

it's the "+" sign that is bugging me.

Comment: Read the "Parent CoroutineContext explained" of https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-first-things-first-e6187bf3bb21

Comment: As the CoroutineContext is a set of elements, a new CoroutineContext will be created with the elements on the right side of the plus overriding those on the left. For better understanding i recommend to check the image demonstration inside the above link.